# Extracting last 2 hours log file from /var/log/messages

Tags: awk

I was trying to extract last 2 hours log file but it is showing some error, please help me to understand this.

```
awk -vDate=`date -d "now-2 hours" "+%b %d %H:%M:%S"` '{if ($3 > Date ) print Date FS $3}' /var/log/messages
```

The output comes:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `00:38:31' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

even I tried like:

```
awk -vDate="$(date -d "now-2 hours" "+%b %d %H:%M:%S")" '{if ($3 > Date ) print Date FS $3}' /var/log/messages
```

Here the output comes:

```
Illegal variable name
```

Please help to understand this :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this:- -vDate="$(date -d "now-2 hours" "+%b %d %H:%M:%S")"   it is showing Illegal variable name

Comment: Are you on a SystemD-based Linux? `journalctl -S-2h` beats awkward `awk`ing.